How to use react hook form with a custom input component (using Zod)?
                <StarRatingInput
                  rating={rating}
                  setRating={(newValue: string) => {
                    setRating(newValue);
                    (
                      document.getElementById("rating") as HTMLInputElement
                    ).value = newValue;
                    console.log("new", newValue);
                  }}
                />
                <input hidden id="rating" type="text" {...register("rating")}/>

In the code above StarRatingInput is a component that is not really a input element but being used as one. As I can not register hook form inside that component, I created a new hidden input tag below it tried to register that instead. As per the above code when rating state changes, the value of input tag also changes. But I am unable to perform validation on rating.
My rating validation is below
  rating: z.string().refine(
    (value: string) => {
      console.log(value);
      const ratings = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
      return ratings.includes(value);
    },
    { message: "Please select valid rating stars" },
  ),

The problem is that the value inside the refine callback function is always empty string.
I can confirm that the value of input tag is changing, but no matter what the value parameter is always empty string.
I also tried changing the input tag to a controlled component but it also didn't work
<input value={rating} id="rating" type="text" {...register("rating")}/>
Implementation of StarRatingInput.tsx
function StarRatingInput({
  rating,
  setRating,
}: {
  rating: string;
  setRating: (newValue: string) => void;
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((star) => {
        return (
          <span
            key={star}
            className="start"
            style={{
              cursor: "pointer",
              color: parseInt(rating) >= star ? "gold" : "gray",
              fontSize: `35px`,
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              setRating(star.toString());
            }}
          >
            {" "}
            ★{" "}
          </span>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default StarRatingInput;


You pretty much never want to directly alter the DOM in react. This is not a good approach with react hook form. If you don't want an form input to manage the user interaction, then you don't want register. React hook form gives you other ways to manage that in a more manual way. Would this solution work for you? https://tsplay.dev/N5d42w It uses getValues and setValue to read/write the form state. If that answers your question, then I can write up a more detailed answer for you.

setValue was exactly what I was looking for. I got it working after reading it in the documentation. Thanks!

This is approach is not advised. You pretty much never want to directly alter the DOM in react.
React hook form provides other ways to interface with non <input> elements.
Namely the getValues and setValue functions.
For example:
  const { getValues, setValue, watch, register } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { name: '', isCool: false }
  })

Now you can access the isCool form state to render that value with:
{ getValues('isCool') ? 'Cool' : 'Not Cool' }

And you can set it by calling setValue:
    <button onClick={() => setValue('isCool', true)}>Cool</button>
    <button onClick={() => setValue('isCool', false)}>Not Cool</button>

One wrinkle though is that react hook form assumes that form state values don't require re-rendering the page. So adding a call to watch tells it to watch for changes on that field and re-render.
  useEffect(() => {
    watch('isCool') // Ensures a re-render when `isCool` is changed.
  }, [])

See playground with type safe but non runnable example.
